# didUpdateToLocation stop call

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, core-location

The following method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

call 1 or 2 times and never more...Why?

```
 -(void) startLocation {
 if (locationManager == nil)
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  }
```

and :

```
       - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
contadorSegundos++;
float diferencaLatitude = 0;
float diferencaLongitude = 0;
NSLog(@"old latitude: %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"old longitude: %f", oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);


NSLog(@"new longitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"old latitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);

if(oldLocation) {
if(oldLocation.coordinate.latitude > newLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    diferencaLatitude = oldLocation.coordinate.latitude - newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
else if(newLocation.coordinate.latitude > oldLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    diferencaLatitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude - oldLocation.coordinate.latitude;
}

if (oldLocation) {

if(oldLocation.coordinate.longitude > newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    diferencaLongitude = oldLocation.coordinate.longitude - newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
else if(newLocation.coordinate.longitude > oldLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    diferencaLongitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude - oldLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}

//NSLog(@"dif lat %f", diferencaLatitude);
```

// NSLog(@"dif long %f", diferencaLongitude);

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
if ((diferencaLatitude > 1) || (diferencaLongitude > 1)) {
    _emMovimento = YES;
    NSLog(@"em movimento");
}
else {
    if(contadorSegundos > 10) {
    _emMovimento = NO;
    contadorSegundos = 0;
        NSLog(@"parado");
    }
}

coord.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
coord.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
_latitude = coord.latitude;
_longitude = coord.longitude;

NSLog(@"latitude: %f", _latitude);
NSLog(@"longitude: %f", _longitude);
MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
[geocoder setDelegate:self];
[geocoder start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was because the ARC release the object LocationManager automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This method is not in use anymore. You must use the method below:

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
   didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

It returns an array of locations, you get the last one.

[locations lastObject]

Answer (score 0):

When you use the filter below you are telling the delegate to only update the location case user change its location for at least 10 meters. Isn`t that what you want? If it`s not, change the desiredAccuracy for best and the distance filter to none.

`locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;`